# How to deploy Orchard Core from localhost to Azure

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I've created an Orchard Core decoupled CMS on my local machine.

Once I finished, I published it to Azure but I get an 500 error. I guess my local database wasn't exported or published to Azure by I don't know how to export everything (binaries and db) from my local machine to Azure.

Do I need to export and import my db from local to Azure and change the connection string everytime I do some changes?

Comment: You should create a database on Azure, you cannot use "local" unless you create a VM where you have control over the disk

Comment: Publishing your code and publishing application data are two distinct operations. Orchard Core has features to export, import and deploy contents, which is probably what you're looking for if I understood your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. What is the name of the feature to export contents? Does it export the content type and items? Or only the types?